# Increase/Decrease font size of all elements in page in angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have a piece of code in my angular component:

```
    IncreaseFontSize()
    {
        let FontSize:any = document.body.style.fontSize;
        if(!FontSize)
        {
            FontSize = 1.4;
        }
        else
        {
            FontSize = parseFloat(FontSize);
        }
        document.body.style.fontSize = (FontSize+0.1) + 'rem';
    }


    DecreaseFontSize()
    {
        let FontSize:any = document.body.style.fontSize;
        if(!FontSize)
        {
            FontSize = 1.4;
        }
        else
        {
            FontSize = parseFloat(FontSize);
        }
        document.body.style.fontSize = (FontSize-0.1) + 'rem';
    }
```

These functions are called upon clicking two buttons, but it is not changing the font size of elements which have a font size already defined for them.

**I need to increase/decrease the font size of all elements**, i.e. if a label has font size 12px, a paragraph with font size of 11px, a div with font size 1.2rem  the should increase their font size by 0.1 rem on click of the increase button.

How should I proceed with the approach?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to use `em` or `rem` for individual elements.

Comment: How do I do that, should I loop through all elements ?

Comment: NOT, you need defined the font-size of all your .css like font-size:1rem, font-size:1.25rem.... Then changing the body font-size you can get it, see e.g. https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. You can see the `div` with `px` does not grow, while other one does.

```js
var fontSize = 16;

function IncreaseFontSize() {
  fontSize = (fontSize + 1);
  document.body.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px';
}


function DecreaseFontSize() {
  fontSize = (fontSize - 1);
  document.body.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px';
}
```

```css
body,
.font-constant {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.font-varies {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="IncreaseFontSize()">+</button>
<button onclick="DecreaseFontSize()">-</button>

<div class="font-varies">
  Hello
</div>

<div class="font-constant">
  how are you?
</div>
```

Comment: I need to make changes in font size to every element

Comment: Have a look at the answer, this is changing the font size on every element where the font size was specified with `em` or `rem`. So you have to constantly use em (or rem) throughout your project than you can adjust the font size for every element with this approach.

Comment: @cloned I cannot make changes to any of the css classes and also it is not changing the font size of the element with class `font-varies`

Comment: Why can't you make changes to css classes? And yes, it changes the font size of the `font-varies` class, the font size gets bigger and smaller when you press the buttons.

Comment: @cloned That's just the requirement that the css classes should not be changed and sorry I meant `font-constant` class not `font-varies`

Comment: That's just an example, it shows that every element where you define it in pixels won't change. If you can't change the css classes then you should post such requirements in the question itself and edit it accordingly. Otherwise this answer is the way to go.

Comment: @cloned I agree, without changing CSS class, this would have to be dealt with a different approach and as a different question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I also would like to get the value of the `fontSize` that comes from the CSS. This is particularly important when you dont initialise this value in the Javascript context nor within the inline CSS in the body tag. The tactic here is basically to save the offset and infer the original value of the css with the unit `rem` which is [the relative font size based on the root element](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp):

```js
  private fontSizeOffset = 0;

  increaseFontSize() {
    document.body.style.setProperty(
      'font-size',
      `calc(1rem + ${++this.fontSizeOffset}px)`
    );
  }

  decreaseFontSize() {
    document.body.style.setProperty(
      'font-size',
      `calc(1rem + ${--this.fontSizeOffset}px)`
    );
  }
```